# Recommendation for socket software

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

I'm learning how to deal with socket programming with `socket()`, `bind()`, `connect()`, `listen()`, etc.

So I'm looking for a socket software that is similar like **[this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockettest/)**, that works in Ubuntu. The software in the link only works in Windows.

Any recommendations?

Comment: @qbi This is a [tag:software-recommendation] question asking for a socket testing utility for Ubuntu. That's clearly on-topic by the FAQ. Not all possible programming questions are on-topic (similarly, not all possible *computer art* questions are on-topic), but software development on Ubuntu is not categorically off-topic. In fact, the FAQ lists it as one of the things that *is on-topic.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something like that is around ...
You could test if a TCP socket is up by connecting to it with `telnet [IP] [port]` see the open ports on a server with `netstat -an` and scan a server for open ports with `nmap`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this a try if there isn't any GUI software around.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the program you linked is just a gui program that does what `nc` does on the command line.